# Is there a sprintf equivalent for node.js

Tags: printf, node.js

Looking to do output formatting (sprintf type functionality) in node.js, but before I write it myself I was wondering if there's something similar built-in (I've trawled the docs to no avail) or if someone's already written a module.

Many thanks

Comment: I would suggest looking at [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format) as well.

Comment: I have since released a fast and spec compliant printf implementation for Node.js and browser https://github.com/gajus/fast-printf

Answer (score 84):

There is now `printf`-like support in [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args).

Example:

```
util.format('hello %s', 'world');
// Returns: 'hello world'
```

Comment: For what it's worth: `function printf() { return process.stdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments)); }

Comment: Also, the support in `util.format` is very very basic: no `%5d` or `%5.3f` or anything like that, so it's not a real `sprintf`-like solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Similar to @Elliot Foster's comment, you could also do `var printf = require('util').format`;

Comment: Docs for node v0.8.2: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.2/api/util.html#util_util_format_format

Comment: @lapo 
floating point number can be rounded using toFixed()

`var a = 1.234567;a.toFixed(3)` => `>'1.235'`

Comment: it's useless, it's not printf-like at all

Comment: Coercing numbers into fixed width string representations, possibly with 0-padding,  is a staple use case for printf-alikes; `util.format` does not support that (eg `require('util').format("blarf_%04d", 42);`) as of v 10.5.0.

Comment: This is deprecated in current versions of node.js.

Answer (score 27):

There are couple in the npm registry which are actual `sprintf` implementations since `util.format` has just a very basic support.

- [<del>sprintf</del>](https://npmjs.org/package/sprintf) (deprecated now)
- [sprintf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js)
- [fast-printf](https://github.com/gajus/fast-printf)

Comment: unfortunately sprintf-js is incompatible with colors: ```sprintf("        %s %s", title.grey, colors['blue'](msg))
'        \x1B[90mTitle\x1B[39m \x1B[34mMessage\x1B[39m'```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the javascript version of `sprintf`:

http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf:522

Answer (score 5):

`console.log` works fine.

```
console.log('%d hours', 4); // 4 hours
console.log('The %2$s contains %1$d monkeys', 4, 'tree'); // The tree contains 4 monkeys
```

Comment: The first example works on Node 0.10.18, but the second completely fails: the 2$/1$ need to be removed to actually get parameter interpolation, and then the parameters need to be in correct order, otherwise you get:

    console.log('The %s contains %d monkeys', 4, 'tree');
returns: 

    The 4 contains NaN monkeys
```

Comment: The second example works in Chrome's (v33) console. Per @FGM, `console.log('The %s contains %d monkeys', 'tree', 4);` works in node v0.10.26.

Comment: useful tip (if it works) but it's equivalent to `printf`, not `sprintf`.

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work on node v9.4, just use `\`es6 template ${format}\``

Answer (score 0):

### Use [locutus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locutus)

As of now, there is a package that translate functions of other languages to Javascript such as php, python, ruby etc.

```
const sprintf = require("locutus/php/strings/sprintf")
const data = sprintf("%01.3f", 2);
console.log(data)
//output: 2.000
```

Try it here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-napier-quyz5?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

### Native Node.js Solution: `util.format(format[, ...args])`

- Expansion of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355266/5795299

#### Example

- Here is a more robust example demonstrating how to parameterize a literal String

```js
import { format } from "util";

const rawURL = "mongodb+srv://%s:%s@myCluster.s73udhj.mongodb.net";
const username = "zappbrannigan";
const password = "VMJta9hdDGymmYMz";

const url = format(rawURL, username, password);

console.log(url);

// Output: "mongodb+srv://zappbrannigan:VMJta9hdDGymmYMz@myCluster.s73udhj.mongodb.net"
```

#### References

- See: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/util.html#utilformatformat-args

Comment: it's so hopeless!  you can't even do %10s etc.